# AngularStrap modal is empty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to create a modal using Angular Strap library:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fXOIAoYMpgzLK4xsvrxG?p=preview

When I run it, I get empty modal, and `$promise.then` this being called before I close the modal.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Whether path of ``some.tpl.html`` is correct?? Modal is not loading this template.  Modal shows ``close`` button where as ``some.tpl.html`` does not have button with ``close`` text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues:

- I wasn't able to get this to work without specifying the modal inside a controller, so I created one.
- Seems like Angular Strap documentation doesn't know what they're talking about. I swapped from using `templateUrl` to using `template`, even though the docs say either should work. Weird.
- From docs, Modal -> Options -> "It should be a `div.modal` element following Bootstrap styles conventions (like this)." with a link leading to https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.tpl.html. So basically you'll need you modal to have all these divs defined around the actual `modal-header`, `modal-body` etc.
- The `$promise.then` part is working as intended; the docs say in an example comment
  `//Show when some event occurs (use $promise property to ensure the template has been loaded)`
  so all it does is ensure that the code inside the `then` function is executed after the modal template has been loaded. You'll likely need a separate handler for your Activate and Close buttons.

Hopefully this helped! Working plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7aNmIK0WTV6aU5raABdQ?p=preview